# Replacing values in multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: r, performance, loops

In the following example, `res` has 90 rows and 6 columns and includes several NAs. There is also a matrix, `tmpCombs` with 6 rows and 2 columns. Each row of `tmpCombs` corresponds to a group of 15 rows in `res` (6*15=90). The number of its columns (2) means that I must replace 2 of the existing NA's in each row of `res` with a specified character (say "B"). (It is ensured that there will be at least 2 NAs in each row).

For example, the values 2 and 4 in row 5 of `tmpCombs` mean that for each row in the group 61-75 `(4*15+1):(5*15)` of `res`, the 2nd and 4th appearing NAs must be replaced with "B".

I can do the job using nested for loops, but I am looking for a faster/massive way to perform those replacements (perhaps using `dplyr` or `data.table`), because my code gets more and more slow, as the dimensions increase.

An example of `res` and `tmpCombs` is given below. There is also a 2nd dataframe, `res2`, which contains the desired output.

```
res <- structure(list(X1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c("A", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    X3 = c(NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
    "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, 
    NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA), X4 = c(NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, 
    NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
    "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, "A", "A", NA), X5 = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, 
    NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, 
    NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, 
    "A"), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, 
    NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", 
    NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")

tmpCombs <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L))

res2 <- structure(list(X1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c("A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X3 = c("B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, 
"B", "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
NA, "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), X4 = c("B", "B", "A", NA, 
NA, "B", "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
"B", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", NA, NA, 
NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"A", NA, "B", "B", "A", NA, NA, "B", "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
"A", "A", "B", NA, NA, "A", "B", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "B"), X5 = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
"A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", NA, "B", 
"B", "A", NA, "B", "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", 
NA, NA, "A", "B", NA, "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", NA, "B", "B", "A", NA, "B", "A", NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, 
NA, "A", "B", NA, NA, "A", "B", NA, "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A"), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
"A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, 
NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmpCombs` can be expanded to get a mapping for each row:

```
tc2 = tmpCombs[rep(seq_len(nrow(tmpCombs)), 
                   each = nrow(res) %/% nrow(tmpCombs)), ]
dim(tc2)
#[1] 90  2
```

Then, looping, only, over the columns and counting the successive appearance of `NA`s, replace when the specific (according to `tmpCombs`) increasing number of `NA` appears:

```
NAcounts = integer(nrow(res))
for(j in seq_along(res)) {
   nas = is.na(res[[j]])

   NAcounts = NAcounts + nas  #`NA`s found so far in each row

   #only for rows with `NA`s 
   #(no need for extended lookup if few rows contain `NA`)
   #check if _this_ appearance of `NA` matches in `tmpCombs`
   wnas = which(nas)
   matches = NAcounts[wnas] == tc2[wnas, ]

   res[[j]][wnas[as.logical(rowSums(matches))]] = "B"
}
identical(res, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest a generalization, that will allow tmpCombs to have an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: @GeorgeDontas : made a few edits; I thought that `as.logical(rowSums(x == y))` (logical -> numeric -> logical) might be excess work than, just, accumulating `|` on the columns of `x == y`, but, I guess, it shouldn't be much inefficient.

Comment: I converted res to a matrix - the code runs much faster in that way. Then I made some necessary changes to your code and got the faster execution. Congrats!

Comment: @GeorgeDontas : I'd expect that using "matrix" might slow things a bit since, generally, `data.frame[[j]]` does not copy while `matrix[, j]` does, and, also, with the above setup there seems to be no overhead from any "data.frame" methods. Or am I missing something in your comment?

Comment: Check out that post for more details http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/permutations-with-repetitions-algorithm-in-r

Comment: @GeorgeDontas : I see, thanks; yes, in that post, `[.data.frame` and `[<-.data.frame` are much more costly than the equivalent "matrix" methods. Though, after creating "res" (and in the current post here), the "data.frame" overhead is not made use of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be much better than your for-loop solution, but here's a possibile option :

```
# Base R solution: 
# note that res is a data.frame of characters but 
# returned value will be a matrix of characters
toBind <- 
lapply(1:nrow(tmpCombs),function(idx){
  rowIdxs<- ((idx-1)*15+1):(idx*15)
  replaceIdxs <- tmpCombs[idx,]
  tmp <- apply(res[rowIdxs,],1,function(row){
    row[na.omit(which(is.na(row))[replaceIdxs])] <- 'B'
    return(row)
  })
  return(t(tmp))
})

fixed <- do.call(rbind,toBind)
```

N.B.

I suggest you to turn `res` into a `matrix` of characters, since usually access to `matrix` elements is faster than `data.frame`